# PowerQuery if with multiple conditions AND OR

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, powerquery, m

How can I replicate this on PowerQuery ??

```
if(ATC[WorkitemAssetState]=64,
if(ATC[WorkitemIsClosed]=FALSE,
if(ATC[WorkitemIsDeleted]=FALSE,
if(ATC[M_WorkitemStatus]IN{"Reviewing","Available","Research","Progressing","Testing","Resolved","<none>"},
if(ATC[M_DefectResolutionId]IN {"-","<Unknown>","Resolution:1","Resolution:7"},1,-1)
,0)
,0)
,0)
,0)
```

I have done the following, but it does not seem to work properly:

```
if [WorkitemAssetState]=64 and 
[WorkitemIsClosed]="FALSE" and
[WorkitemIsDeleted]="FALSE" and
[M_WorkitemStatus]="Reviewing" or [M_WorkitemStatus]= "Available" or [M_WorkitemStatus]= "Research" or [M_WorkitemStatus] = "Progressing" or [M_WorkitemStatus] = "Testing" or [M_WorkitemStatus] = "Resolved" or [M_WorkitemStatus] = "<none>" or [M_WorkitemStatus] = "<none>" or [M_WorkitemStatus] = "-" and
[M_DefectResolutionId]= "-" or [M_DefectResolutionId] = "<Unknown>" or [M_DefectResolutionId] = "Resolution:1" or[M_DefectResolutionId] = "Resolution:7" then 1 else 0
```

I am pretty sure it's because of the multiple OR statements.
I don't think it's because of the `FALSE`'s, btw.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure about the priorities of "and" and "or", it's better to use parentheses.

In fact, "and"'s are evaluated first, then "or"'s.
So "a and b or c and d" is equivalent with "(a and b) or (c and d)".
Not with "a and (b or c) and d", which - I understand - you are looking for.
If so, you need to add parentheses around the collections of "or"'s.

Assuming you have logical values, then "FALSE" won't work: you need *false* without quotes and in all lower case.

By the way "does not seem to work properly" is not exactly the preferred way to explain what is going wrong. I guess you get (almost) all 1's and (almost) no 0's?

Comment: Thanks, I used the parenthesis in the end and it was all fine